# Bayesian Linear Regression and the Exponential Family

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, generalized-linear-model, sufficient-statistics, exponential-family

In a straight forward linear regression model, assuming a fixed input $\mathbf{x}$, and additive noise with unit variance we can write:

\begin{equation}
p(y\mid \mathbf{x,w})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma^2}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(y-\mathbf{w}\cdot\mathbf{x})^2 \right),
\end{equation}

from which point we can expand the square and collect the terms such that the expression fits within the exponential family framework. In particular if we assume the exponential family has the form:

\begin{equation}
 f_{X}(x\mid \theta )=h(x)\exp \left[\eta (\theta )\cdot T(x)-A(\theta )\right]
\end{equation}

then we can see that $\eta(\theta) = [\mathbf{w}\cdot\mathbf{x}/\sigma^2, -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} ]$, $T(x) = [y,y^2]^\intercal$, where the remaining terms can be collected as needed.

I am interested in extending this to Bayesian linear regression, in particular I consider some extension:

$p(y,\mathbf{w} \mid \mathbf{x},\beta)$ = $p(y\mid \mathbf{x,w})p(\mathbf{w}\mid \beta)$, where I add some Gaussian prior over the weights, such that I have the expression (once again considering unit variance):

\begin{equation}
p(y,\mathbf{w} \mid \mathbf{x},\beta) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma^2}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(y-\mathbf{w}\cdot\mathbf{x})^2 \right)\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma^2}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(\mathbf{\beta}-\mathbf{w})^{\intercal} \mathbf{\Sigma} (\mathbf{\beta}-\mathbf{w}) \right)
\end{equation}

---

***Question:***

Is it possible to express this via the exponential family? As I understand both likelihood and prior need the same $\eta(\theta)$ term to appear, but in the likelihood we have the expression $ \mathbf{w\cdot x}$, but only $\mathbf{w}$ in the prior, and I am not finding it easy to massage $\mathbf{w}$ into a form which has something like "$\mathbf{w\cdot x / x}$" going on. Perhaps we can consider something like $\mathbf{w}\cdot 1$, s.t. $\mathbf{x}$ is constrained to lie on $\mathbf{x}=1$?

Therefore is it possible to express the above model via the exponential family form? If so, how would the log partition function look like? Is there a proof somewhere online I can inspect for this?

If the above answer is yes, would your solution extend naturally to the case of $\phi(\mathbf{w\cdot x})$ (i.e. non-linear transformation)?

Intuitively in the linear case I believe the answer should be yes, as Gaussians are closed under multiplication, but the algebra for this one corner case has stumped me a little...

Comment: It is true that $\boldsymbol{y}$ and $\boldsymbol{w}$ are jointly Normally distributed given $\boldsymbol{x}$. However, this means that the distribution is no longer univariate. Of course, you can still write it in exponential form if you like. For your extension, note that $\boldsymbol{w}$ is normally does not imply $\phi(\boldsymbol{w} \cdot \boldsymbol{x})$ will be.

Comment: So I would need to find an entirely new set of statistics and natural parameters? 

From some sources on the internet they suggest that with a valid conjugate prior both probability distributions (llhood and prior) should have the same natural params and suff. stats (s.t. it is easy to combine them into one final exponential family - essentially a shifted one). Since this cannot be done here, does this suggest my conj prior is not a valid conj prior (even though it really feels like one!)

Comment: You do have a valid conjugate prior. However, typically one is interested in estimating $\boldsymbol{w}$. Your question makes it sound like you're interested in estimating $\boldsymbol{\beta}$. So do you want sufficient stats for $\boldsymbol{w}$ or $\boldsymbol{\beta}$?

Comment: I think your statement has given me a lightbulb. (1) I began with some $p(y|x,w)$. (2) I wanted to add a conjugate prior over $w$ which means I wanted to consider $p(y,w|x,\beta) = p(y|x,w)p(w|\beta)$. And there is also (3) $p(w|y,x,\beta)\propto  p(y|x,w)p(w|\beta)=p(y,w|x,\beta)$. Now, I assumed the natural parameters (and suff. stats.) between models (1) and (2) should be of the same form/type. However most conjugacy formulas online only consider case (3)? i.e. the posterior. For my case I am interested case (2) - so maybe "prior" as a term has mixed me up there (it's just product rule)!

Comment: Sufficient statistics were frequentist concepts developed for forming estimators of fixed parameters. That's why when you introduced priors it makes it quite confusing. I supposed that your "prior" was just a device. You weren't really interested in a Bayesian analysis. In that case, you turned your linear regression problem into something else, and that's why the sufficient stats are now quite different from before.